# Edit each file in a folder

Tags: vbscript

I have a function to replace a specific string in a text file. This works well for a specific file (test.conf) without any problems. But now I'm looking for a way to check each file in the directory for this string. Is there a way to check all files in the directory and find and replace the string in each file? I'm not really sure how to use the For Each File function.

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(operations & "\test.conf", ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strText = Replace(strText, "$$Username:$$", username)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(operations & "\test.conf", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strText
objFile.Close
```

This is my solution for the specific file "test.conf".
But there could be more files in this folder with the `$$Username:$$` string in it.

Example:

```
\FOLDER\test.conf
\FOLDER\abc.conf
\FOLDER\def.conf
...
```

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/wz72a8c0%28v%3dvs.84%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to loop through each .conf file:

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

dim sFolder : sFolder = "C:\Temp\"
dim oFSO : Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim oFile, objFile, strText

For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
  If UCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "CONF" Then

    Set objFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(oFile.Path, ForReading)
    strText = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close
    Set objFile = Nothing

    strText = Replace(strText, "texttoreplace", "newtext")
    Set objFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(oFile.Path, ForWriting)
    objFile.WriteLine strText
    objFile.Close
    Set objFile = Nothing

  End if
Next

Set oFSO = Nothing
```